# Button return Id in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, post, get, twig

This is my PHP code where i am trying to get the "**ApartmentId**" when the button "**myOnbutton**" is being clicked.

```
if (isset($_POST['myOnbutton'])) {
            $providerstatss = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('myBundle:UserStats')
                    ->findByApartmentId($_POST);
        }
```

This is my code for my button in twig ---

```
  <form method="post" action="#">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Content Management</h3>           
            <table class="table table-content">
<tbody>


         {% for userStats in userStats %}    
    <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">ON</button> 
        </td> </tbody>
                </table></form>
```

It is not working for me, i am also not sure about this method **->findByApartmentId($_POST);** , the column name is "**ApartmentId**".

So I need to actually get the "UserStats.ApartmentId" when the button clicked.

How can I get the "ApartmentId" when the button is clicked?

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: I see several things wrong--please post the entire html form.

Comment: 1) `$_POST` is an array, so you have to use a key to extract a value (like `$_POST['ApartmentId']`)

2) The form is missing any field apart from the button, so where is your `ApartmentId` value inside that form?

Comment: @Matteo'Ingannatore'G. i have update my question, can you kindly have a look...

Comment: I'm sorry but your Twig is still incorrect:
1) You have a `{% for userStats in userStats %}` without an `{% endfor %}`
2) Your form is still missing a value for `ApartmentId` (the button alone is useless)

Comment: @Matteo'Ingannatore'G. Can you kindly give me an answer how should i implement ApartmentId in my form :)

Comment: You should check out the answer made by Mathieu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do not use the powers of Symfony2 and Twig**

Try this

### Twig :

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Content Management</h3>
    <table class="table table-content">
        <tbody>
        {% for user in userStats %}
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('mybundle_apartment',{ apartmentId: user.ApartmentId }) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">ON</a>
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
// ....
/**
* @Route("/apartment/{id}", name="mybundle_apartment")
*/
public function apartmentAction($id)
{
    if (null !== ($request->get('myOnbutton'))) {

        $providerstatss = $this->getDoctrine()
                          ->getRepository('myBundle:UserStats')
                          ->findBy(array('ApartmentId' => $id));
    }
}
// ....
```

Or you can find direclty your entity with ParamConverter like :

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
// ....
/**
* @Route("/apartment/{id}", name="bundlename_apartment")
* @ParamConverter("apartment", class="myBundle:UserStats")
*/
public function apartmentAction($apartment)
{
    var_dump($apartment);
    // ...
}
```